# Update nested object values by array notation in reactjs state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I have some generic code that attempts to update specific states. It's possible to access an object by the keys in an array, e.g:

```
let x = {person: { name: "Dennis"}} 
console.log(x["person"]["name"])
```

In react, it is possible (and often used in input validation), to access a specific state-key by array, e.g:

```
//event.target.name = input field property name="firstName"
this.setState({
    [event.target.name]: event.target.value
});
```

Which would update `this.state.firstName` to the inputs value.

I am trying to bind nested complex objects to inputs, to avoid having translation functions. So if my state contains `{ person: {name : "" } }` I want to access it dynamically by this.state["person"]["name"] - which works. I want to use the same notation in `setState`, because then I can bind my nested state-data to inputs like this: `<input name="person.name" />` and in my change handler I can look for periods: `if(ev.target.name.split("."))...`

However, I can't seem to access the state in the same way in setState, because it's an object, so:

```
const args = ev.target.name.split(".");
this.setState({
    [args[0]][args[1]]: ev.target.value
});
```

Is there anyway to do this?

Comment: You can do it like in the following question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43040721/how-to-update-a-nested-state-in-react/43041334#43041334

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out this was a bit more complicated than initially thought. By using Object.assign all nested objects kept their immutable properties, which made it impossible to change them. I had to make a hard copy of the state, in order to change it. With the use of _set from [lodash.set](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.5#set)  it could be done in very few lines:

```
//Create a hard-copy of the state
let stateCopy = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.state));

//Update the value in the state with the input value
_set(stateCopy, ev.target.name, ev.target.value);

//Set the state with the changed value
this.setState(stateCopy);
```

Edit: Only downside is that currently I copy the entire state in the setState() and not just the delta values.

Answer (score 0):

I like to use ramda for this. 
It would look like

```
this.setState(R.assocPath(args, ev.target.value))
```

Answer (score 0):

Its a little more complicated, you could deep copy the objects:

```
 const args = ev.target.name.split(".");
 let result = {};
 const root = result;
 let pos = this.state;
 const last = args.pop();
 for(const arg of args) {
   Object.assign(result, pos);
   result = result[arg] || (result[arg] = {});
   pos = pos[arg] || {};
 }
 result[last] = evt.target.value;
 this.setState(root);
```

Comment: At first I thought it didn't work because you used pop (which effectively removes the last element from the stack, and so the iteration only loops over the first one), but I have problems with setting read-only properties as well, when result is reassigned after the first iteration.